# swift autolayout crash in NSISEngine in ios7

Tags: swift, autolayout

Minimal test case that crashes autolayout when transitioning back.  Not so much a question as a warning to others, since I couldn't find anything clear about this after much googling.

https://github.com/delackner/SwiftAutolayoutCrash

Run the app, then press GO twice (transitioning via pushViewController)
then press BACK twice (transitioning via popViewController)

Crashes pretty horribly on IOS7.1.1 and IOS7.1.2 *devices*, not on the simulator.

The meaningful part is all in ViewController.swift

What's interesting to me, and made me want to invite discussion, is that this works fine on IOS7 simulator and ios8 simulator, generates no warnings, no console warning output, yet crashes really ugly on an actual device.

reproduced below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Disable this line to get a sense of the navigation transitions
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let (add, views) = makeAdder(self.view)

    let iconFrame = UIView.newAutoLayoutView()
    add(iconFrame, "iconFrame")
    fillIconFrame(iconFrame)

    let bOK = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
    bOK.addTarget(self, action: Selector("next:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    bOK.setTitle("GO", forState: .Normal)
    add(bOK, "ok")

    let l = UILabel.newAutoLayoutView()
    add(l, "text")
    l.text = "To Crash: Press GO At least twice, then back twice"
    l.autoCenterInSuperview()

    //THIS WORKS FINE
    //l.autoSetDimension(.Width, toSize: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.8)

    //THIS CRASHES
    l.autoMatchDimension(.Width, toDimension: .Width, ofView: self.view, withMultiplier: 0.8)

    VFL(self.view, "V:[iconFrame][text][ok]", .AlignAllCenterX, nil, views)

    iconFrame.autoMatchDimension(.Width, toDimension: .Width, ofView: l)
    bOK.autoMatchDimension(.Width, toDimension: .Width, ofView: l)
}

func next(sender:AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(TestViewController(), animated: true)
}
```

error output:

```
2014-08-26 12:39:29.106 Crash[1420:60b] Objective: {objective 0x178034360: <250:1305> + <250:-1>*0x170093100.marker{id: 236} + <250:1>*0x170093330.marker{id: 267} + <250:-1>*0x170093560.marker{id: 244} + <250:1>*0x170096620.marker{id: 270} + <250:-1>*0x170096d50.marker{id: 240} + <250:-1>*0x170096da0.marker{id: 242} + <750:1, 250:-2>*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297} + <250:3>*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + <750:1>*0x1780baac0.negError{id: 299} + <250:1>*0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x1780bad60.negError{id: 288} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x1780bae80.negError{id: 293} + <750:1>*0x1780baee0.negError{id: 290} + <250:1>*0x1780baee0.posErrorMarker{id: 289} + <750:1>*0x1780bb300.negError{id: 295} + <250:1>*0x1780bb300.posErrorMarker{id: 294} + <250:-1.19209e-07>*0x1780bba20.negError{id: 403}}
2014-08-26 12:39:29.127 Crash[1420:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<NSISEngine: 0x178121860>{ Rows:
    0x1780bad60.posErrorMarker{id: 287} == 585 + -1*0x170093100.marker{id: 236} + -1*0x170096d50.marker{id: 240} + -1*0x170096da0.marker{id: 242} + -1*0x170093560.marker{id: 244} + 1*0x170093330.marker{id: 267} + 1*0x1780bad60.negError{id: 288} + 1*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    0x1780bae80.posErrorMarker{id: 292} == 720 + 1*0x170096620.marker{id: 270} + 1*0x1780bae80.negError{id: 293} + 1*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UIButton:0x15c618a20.Height{id: 266} == 60 + 1*0x1780bb300.posErrorMarker{id: 294} + -1*0x1780bb300.negError{id: 295}
    UIButton:0x15c618a20.Width{id: 265} == 780 + 1*0x170096620.marker{id: 270} + 1*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UIButton:0x15c618a20.minX{id: 264} == 98 + 1*0x170093740.marker{id: 253} + -1.25*0x170093d30.marker{id: 255} + -1*0x170093600.marker{id: 263} + -0.5*0x170096620.marker{id: 270} + 0.125*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -0.125*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UIButton:0x15c618a20.minY{id: 260} == 21 + 1*0x170093fb0.marker{id: 247} + 0.5*UIView:0x170170bc0.Height{id: 252} + 1*0x170093f10.marker{id: 259} + 0.5*0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298} + -0.5*0x1780baac0.negError{id: 299}
    UILabel:0x15c603eb0.Height{id: 291} == 42 + 1*0x1780baee0.posErrorMarker{id: 289} + -1*0x1780baee0.negError{id: 290}
    UILabel:0x15c603eb0.Width{id: 246} == 683 + -1*0x170093100.marker{id: 236} + -1*0x170096d50.marker{id: 240} + -1*0x170096da0.marker{id: 242} + -1*0x170093560.marker{id: 244} + 1*0x170093330.marker{id: 267} + 1*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UILabel:0x15c603eb0.minX{id: 243} == 96 + 1*0x170093100.marker{id: 236} + 1*0x170096d50.marker{id: 240} + 1*0x170096da0.marker{id: 242}
    UILabel:0x15c617f50.Height{id: 251} == 42 + 1*0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298} + -1*0x1780baac0.negError{id: 299}
    UILabel:0x15c617f50.Width{id: 249} == 780 + 1*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UILabel:0x15c617f50.minX{id: 248} == 98 + 1*0x170093740.marker{id: 253} + -1.25*0x170093d30.marker{id: 255} + 0.125*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -0.125*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UILabel:0x15c617f50.minY{id: 250} == -21 + 1*0x170093fb0.marker{id: 247} + 0.5*UIView:0x170170bc0.Height{id: 252} + -0.5*0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298} + 0.5*0x1780baac0.negError{id: 299}
    UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.Height{id: 94} == 2048 + 2*0x178094e10.marker{id: 105} + 1*0x1780951d0.marker{id: 113}
    UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.Width{id: 89} == 1543 + 2*0x178094d70.marker{id: 100} + 1*0x178095180.marker{id: 110}
    UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.minX{id: 97} == 0 + 2*0x178094d20.marker{id: 96} + -1*0x178094d70.marker{id: 100}
    UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.minY{id: 98} == 0 + 2*0x178094dc0.marker{id: 103} + -1*0x178094e10.marker{id: 105}
    UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.Height{id: 84} == 2048 + 2*0x1780949b0.marker{id: 95} + 2*0x178094e10.marker{id: 105} + 1*0x1780951d0.marker{id: 113}
    UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.Width{id: 79} == 1539 + 2*0x178094910.marker{id: 90} + 2*0x178094d70.marker{id: 100} + 1*0x178095180.marker{id: 110}
    UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.minX{id: 87} == 0 + 2*0x1780948c0.marker{id: 86} + -1*0x178094910.marker{id: 90}
    UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.minY{id: 88} == 0 + 2*0x178094960.marker{id: 93} + -1*0x1780949b0.marker{id: 95}
    UIView:0x170170bc0.Width{id: 254} == 976 + -2.5*0x170093d30.marker{id: 255} + 1.25*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1.25*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UIView:0x170171340.Height{id: 239} == 96 + 1*0x170093060.marker{id: 238}
    UIView:0x170171340.Width{id: 237} == 96 + 1*0x170093100.marker{id: 236}
    UIView:0x170171340.minX{id: 241} == 0 + 1*0x170096d50.marker{id: 240}
    UIView:0x170171640.Width{id: 245} == 779 + 1*0x170093330.marker{id: 267} + 1*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -1*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UIView:0x170171640.minX{id: 262} == 98 + 1*0x170093740.marker{id: 253} + -1.25*0x170093d30.marker{id: 255} + 1*0x1700937e0.marker{id: 261} + -0.5*0x170093330.marker{id: 267} + 0.125*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + -0.125*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297}
    UIView:0x170171640.minY{id: 258} == -21 + 1*0x170093fb0.marker{id: 247} + 0.5*UIView:0x170170bc0.Height{id: 252} + -1*0x170093dd0.marker{id: 256} + -1*UIView:0x170171640.Height{id: 257} + -0.5*0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298} + 0.5*0x1780baac0.negError{id: 299}
    UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.Height{id: 74} == 2048 + 2*0x178094550.marker{id: 85} + 2*0x1780949b0.marker{id: 95} + 2*0x178094e10.marker{id: 105} + 1*0x1780951d0.marker{id: 113}
    UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.Width{id: 69} == 1534 + 2*0x1780944b0.marker{id: 80} + 2*0x178094910.marker{id: 90} + 2*0x178094d70.marker{id: 100} + 1*0x178095180.marker{id: 110}
    UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.minX{id: 77} == 0 + 2*0x178094460.marker{id: 76} + -1*0x1780944b0.marker{id: 80}
    UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.minY{id: 78} == 0 + 2*0x178094500.marker{id: 83} + -1*0x178094550.marker{id: 85}
    UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.Height{id: 104} == 2048 + 1*0x1780951d0.marker{id: 113}
    UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.Width{id: 99} == 1536 + 1*0x178095180.marker{id: 110}
    UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.minX{id: 107} == 0 + 2*0x1780bb3c0.marker{id: 106} + -0.5*0x178095180.marker{id: 110}
    UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.minY{id: 109} == 0 + 2*0x1780bb420.marker{id: 108} + -0.5*0x1780951d0.marker{id: 113}
    objective{id: 1} == {objective 0x178034360: <250:1305> + <250:-1>*0x170093100.marker{id: 236} + <250:1>*0x170093330.marker{id: 267} + <250:-1>*0x170093560.marker{id: 244} + <250:1>*0x170096620.marker{id: 270} + <250:-1>*0x170096d50.marker{id: 240} + <250:-1>*0x170096da0.marker{id: 242} + <750:1, 250:-2>*0x1780ba700.negError{id: 297} + <250:3>*0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296} + <750:1>*0x1780baac0.negError{id: 299} + <250:1>*0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x1780bad60.negError{id: 288} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x1780bae80.negError{id: 293} + <750:1>*0x1780baee0.negError{id: 290} + <250:1>*0x1780baee0.posErrorMarker{id: 289} + <750:1>*0x1780bb300.negError{id: 295} + <250:1>*0x1780bb300.posErrorMarker{id: 294} + <250:-1.19209e-07>*0x1780bba20.negError{id: 403}}

Constraints:
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094460 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.midX == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.midX>        Marker:0x178094460.marker{id: 76} (Integralization adjustment:-1.25)
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1780944b0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.width == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.width>      Marker:0x1780944b0.marker{id: 80} (Integralization adjustment:-2.5)
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094500 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.midY == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.midY>        Marker:0x178094500.marker{id: 83}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094550 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.height == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.height>        Marker:0x178094550.marker{id: 85}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1780948c0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.midX == UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.midX>      Marker:0x1780948c0.marker{id: 86} (Integralization adjustment:-1)
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094910 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.width>        Marker:0x178094910.marker{id: 90} (Integralization adjustment:-2)
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094960 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.midY == UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.midY>      Marker:0x178094960.marker{id: 93}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1780949b0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.height == UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.height>      Marker:0x1780949b0.marker{id: 95}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094d20 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.midX == UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.midX>        Marker:0x178094d20.marker{id: 96} (Integralization adjustment:1.75001)
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094d70 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.width == UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.width>      Marker:0x178094d70.marker{id: 100} (Integralization adjustment:3.50001)
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094dc0 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.midY == UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.midY>        Marker:0x178094dc0.marker{id: 103}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094e10 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.height == UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.height>        Marker:0x178094e10.marker{id: 105}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178095180 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0(768)]>      Marker:0x178095180.marker{id: 110}
    <NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1780951d0 h=--- v=--- V:[UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0(1024)]>     Marker:0x1780951d0.marker{id: 113}
    <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1780ba700 H:[UILabel:0x15c617f50(390)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>      Marker:0x1780ba700.posErrorMarker{id: 296}
    <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1780baac0 V:[UILabel:0x15c617f50(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>       Marker:0x1780baac0.posErrorMarker{id: 298}
    <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1780bad60 H:[UILabel:0x15c603eb0(49)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>       Marker:0x1780bad60.posErrorMarker{id: 287}
    <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1780bae80 H:[UIButton:0x15c618a20(30)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>      Marker:0x1780bae80.posErrorMarker{id: 292}
    <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1780baee0 V:[UILabel:0x15c603eb0(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>       Marker:0x1780baee0.posErrorMarker{id: 289}
    <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x1780bb300 V:[UIButton:0x15c618a20(30)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>      Marker:0x1780bb300.posErrorMarker{id: 294}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093060 V:[UIView:0x170171340(48)]>     Marker:0x170093060.marker{id: 238}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093100 H:[UIView:0x170171340(48)]>     Marker:0x170093100.marker{id: 236}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093330 UIView:0x170171640.width == UILabel:0x15c617f50.width>      Marker:0x170093330.marker{id: 267} (Integralization adjustment:-1)
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093560 H:[UILabel:0x15c603eb0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170171640 )>       Marker:0x170093560.marker{id: 244}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093600 UILabel:0x15c617f50.centerX == UIButton:0x15c618a20.centerX>        Marker:0x170093600.marker{id: 263}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093740 UILabel:0x15c617f50.centerX == UIView:0x170170bc0.centerX>      Marker:0x170093740.marker{id: 253}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700937e0 UIView:0x170171640.centerX == UILabel:0x15c617f50.centerX>      Marker:0x1700937e0.marker{id: 261} (Integralization adjustment:-0.5)
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093d30 UILabel:0x15c617f50.width == 0.8*UIView:0x170170bc0.width>      Marker:0x170093d30.marker{id: 255} (Integralization adjustment:-0.4)
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093dd0 V:[UIView:0x170171640]-(0)-[UILabel:0x15c617f50]>       Marker:0x170093dd0.marker{id: 256}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093f10 V:[UILabel:0x15c617f50]-(0)-[UIButton:0x15c618a20]>     Marker:0x170093f10.marker{id: 259}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093fb0 UILabel:0x15c617f50.centerY == UIView:0x170170bc0.centerY>      Marker:0x170093fb0.marker{id: 247}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170096620 UIButton:0x15c618a20.width == UILabel:0x15c617f50.width>        Marker:0x170096620.marker{id: 270}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170096d50 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x170171340]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170171640 )>        Marker:0x170096d50.marker{id: 240}
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170096da0 H:[UIView:0x170171340]-(0)-[UILabel:0x15c603eb0]>       Marker:0x170096da0.marker{id: 242}
    <_UIWindowAnchoringConstraint:0x1780bb3c0 h=--- v=--- UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.midX == + 384>       Marker:0x1780bb3c0.marker{id: 106}
    <_UIWindowAnchoringConstraint:0x1780bb420 h=--- v=--- UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.midY == + 512>       Marker:0x1780bb420.marker{id: 108}

Integralization Adjustments:
0x170093330.marker{id: 267} [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093330 UIView:0x170171640.width == UILabel:0x15c617f50.width>] -> -1.000000
0x1700937e0.marker{id: 261} [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700937e0 UIView:0x170171640.centerX == UILabel:0x15c617f50.centerX>] -> -0.500000
0x170093d30.marker{id: 255} [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170093d30 UILabel:0x15c617f50.width == 0.8*UIView:0x170170bc0.width>] -> -0.400000
0x178094460.marker{id: 76} [<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094460 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.midX == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.midX>] -> -1.250000
0x1780944b0.marker{id: 80} [<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1780944b0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x178170140.width == UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.width>] -> -2.500000
0x1780948c0.marker{id: 86} [<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1780948c0 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.midX == UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.midX>] -> -1.000000
0x178094910.marker{id: 90} [<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094910 h=-&- v=-&- UINavigationTransitionView:0x1701e1c00.width == UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.width>] -> -2.000000
0x178094d20.marker{id: 96} [<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094d20 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.midX == UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.midX>] -> 1.750005
0x178094d70.marker{id: 100} [<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x178094d70 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0x1701a79a0.width == UIWindow:0x15c50b0e0.width>] -> 3.500011

Statistics:
    36 rows. Variable counts:
        1 ->   5
        2 ->  14
        3 ->   6
        4 ->   5
        5 ->   1
        6 ->   3
        7 ->   1
        8 ->   1
}: internal error.  Cannot find an outgoing row head for incoming head 0x1780bba20.negError{id: 403}, which should never happen.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1816cf100 0x18df881fc 0x1816cf040 0x1821b86a8 0x1821b81ac 0x1821b384c 0x184691cdc 0x1849633b4 0x184690840 0x1847695a4 0x184846f40 0x1847c2af4 0x18493c794 0x1846d06fc 0x1846d0284 0x1846d0180 0x18428b888 0x18e55ffd4 0x18e5631dc 0x18168eddc 0x18168d11c 0x1815cddd0 0x18725dc0c 0x1846fefc4 0x1000f8550 0x1000f8590 0x18e57baa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Noone had find solutions for this problem? I have the same :(